# Excel 2007 Crash on "Page Layout" tab click

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

The title pretty much say says it all; when I click on the `Page Layout` tab in the ribbon bar at the top, Excel freezes and then crashes. How can I solve this?

All the other tabs work fine...

**EDIT**

I noticed that it also crashes when I try to format anything in a table. Maybe these problems are related...?

I'm on Windows 7 Home Edition if that helps anybody...

Comment: any notes in the application event log about a possible failing DLL?

Comment: How do I find the application event log?

Comment: right click on Computer or My Computer and select "Manage".  expand "Event viewer" then click "application"

Answer (score 0):

Delete and reinstall your printer or check for updated drivers. As a check you could also delete all printers and add a safe generic one such as an HP LaserJet 4 and see what happens. Crashes in the Page Layout section are often related to printers/printer drivers.